# I have text box for datepicker via JQuery but datepicker is not working

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

Jquery datepicker is not working. Here is my code. I know I am either missing some JS file or have included some overriding JS file but which one is that,I want to know.

Please check my code and let me know what I am missing or what is extra added in js file which block the jquery datepicker. Although, it was working before but after a code refactoring, it stopped to work

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="./css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
 <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<link href="./css/lightbox.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<!-- <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> -->
<link href="./css/chosen.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="./css/angular-bootstrap-lightbox.min.css"/>
<link href="./css/font-awesome.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="./css/select2.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/flexslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/circle.css">
<link href="./css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="./css/select2.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/flexslider.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/circle.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/formValidation.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"  rel = "stylesheet">
 <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/DatePicker.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/uploadImage.js"></script> 
</head>
<body class="bodybg">

<div class="container img-fluid">
    <form action="../CompleteRegistration" method="post"
        id="registrationForm" onsubmit="return validateCompleteRegistrationForm()"
        class="needs-validation  box text-secondary" enctype='multipart/form-data' novalidate>
        <h3 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 50px;">Complete Your
            Form</h3>
        <div style="text-align: center;"
            class="mediumtxt c7 padt4 padb15 fleft mpaddl10">Take the last
            step in finding your soulmate by providing your basic information.
            It's simple and easy.</div>
    <div class="clear-both"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <label for="validationCustomUsername">Date Of Birth</label> <input
                            type="text" class="form-control forFont hasDatepicker" id="userDateofBirth"
                            autocomplete="off" name="userDateofBirth"
                            placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend"
                            required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter Date of Birth</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
This is my jquery code for datepicker
  $(function() {
  $( "#userDateofBirth" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth:true,
    changeYear:true,
    yearRange:"1940:currentYear",
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
      numberOfMonths:[1,1]
    });
  });
```

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+i` in you browser to open the inspect element and open the networking tab to see the unloaded files and make sure you load the correct ones

Comment: i checked in the network tab and all files are loaded correctly

Comment: `./js/DatePicker.js` what does this has ?,also you have included two jquery i.e :`./js/jquery.js` and  `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js`.

Comment: I have tried after removing one of the js file but no luck. DatePicker.js is js file where condition is written

Comment: Try to remove and add `scripts` one by one and check which `script` is affecting datepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  
  <div >
   <input type="text"  class="form-control datepicker" readonly>
  </div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      format: 'dd-M-yyyy',
  });
    
   

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```